# Is there a JsRender render completed event

Tags: jsrender

Is there a JsRender event or callback to determine when a render method has completed?  I'm wanting to process a number of templates and ensure that they've all completed before I grab the resulting document element.  Are all render method run synchronously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsRender renders templates synchronously, there is no callback function, the `.render()` function just returns the rendered data.

When you do have multiple asynchronous processes (such as ajax calls that return data that you then render with jsRender), and you need all of them to complete before performing some action, you can use jQuery's Deferred objects. Look into [.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) for how to do that.

Comment: Yes, when you have inserted the rendered content into the DOM (e.g. _$(...).html( $.render.myTmpl(data) );_ (which is synchronous) you can then immediately (on the next line) call _$(...).on(...)_ to attach handlers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to determine when the last row has been rendered by the templating engine. 
a) create a helper function. in this case called: jsRenderDone
then in the template at the bottom use conditional logic that fires the helper function only after the last row has been rendered.

```
{{if #index+1 >= #get("array").data.length}}
{{:~jsRenderDone()}} {{/if}}
```